# Django static_root in /var/www/... - no permissions to collectstatic

Tags: linux, django, permissions

My STATIC_ROOT folder is specified to be `/var/www/app_name/static`, which is usually should not be accessed by non-sudo users.

It was created by a user with sudo rights. Now i am trying to `collectstatic` with my own user and it says `"Permission denied..."`, not surprisingly.

How should I properly collect static files? Under which user?

Comment: `sudo python manage.py collecstatic`

Comment: @trantu doesnt work, because then sudo pick ups global python version, and i am running my app in virtualenv

Comment: It does not make sense that static folder can be only accessed by root users. There are also css, js files.

Comment: Try [How to use a python virtualenv with sudo?](http://askubuntu.com/q/234758/412416), it would be a hassle to change the ownership each time you need to deploy a new version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take ownership of `/var/www/app_name/static` then put it back the way it was.

```
$ sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /var/www/app_name/static
$ python manage.py collectstatic
$ sudo chown -R root:root /var/www/app_name/static
```

Comment: @James Fenwick any way to automate this with a fabfile? I saw some options for collectstatic onto a remote host but not for localhost

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way you should add current user to group `www-data`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$ python manage.py collectstatic`, the `manage.py` program attempts to write the static files it finds within your Django project into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory.  99% of the time, when a Linux program attempts to manipulate files, it does so as the user who invokes the program.  That's true in the case of `manage.py`, where the user that runs this program is almost certainly your regular login user.  Whichever user it is, I'll call it 'denys'.  Thus, 'denys' must have write permissions on the `STATIC_ROOT` directory, which in your case is `/var/www/app_name/static/`.

The most ham-fisted way to obtain these permissions is to make 'denys' the owner of the directory (and to ensure that the directory has 'w' permissions for the owner, which it almost certainly already does).  That can be done like so:

```
$ sudo chown denys /var/www/app_name/static
$ sudo chmod u+w /var/www/app_name/static
```

However, you mention that this folder was created by "a user with sudo rights," which may or may not be 'denys'.  That user, presumably, wants to keep ownership of the folder.  This scenario is precisely why Linux has *groups*.

The most proper way to handle this situation is to create a group specifically for managing the files in `/var/www/app_name/static`.  I'll propose 'django', which should be available unless you've already created a group by that name for some other purpose (some programs, like MySQL and Apache, create their own `user:group` entities on installation.  Django does not, but you can verify this by inspecting `/etc/group`; i.e., `$ grep "django" /etc/group` should return nothing).  If you don't like 'django', you can use whatever you want.

To create the group:

```
$ sudo groupadd django
```

Then, add 'denys' to the group:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G django denys
```

(remember, 'denys' is a placeholder for whatever user is invoking the `collectstatic` command).  If it's a different user that owns the folder, you can also add that user to the group, and depending on your setup you may wish to add 'root' or your webserver user (like Apache's 'www-data') to the 'django' group.  These weren't necessary for my Django app to work, but you might have a different setup.

Now, make 'django' the group owner of the `STATIC_ROOT` folder:

```
$ sudo chgrp django /var/www/app_name/static
```

and make sure the group has write permissions on it:

```
$ sudo chmod g+w /var/www/app_name/static
```

On my Ubuntu 18.04 setup, the group owner **does not** have write permission here by default, and that's probably common among distributions, so that last line is important.

`$ ls -ld /var/www/app_name/static` should now look something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  root django  /var/www/app_name/static
```

where instead of 'root' you might have some other user as the owner, and you can verify that 'denys' is a member of the 'django' group by running `$ groups denys` and looking for `django` in the output.

Now, the annoying bit, because Linux can't do anything without a dose of user-hostility.  If 'denys' tries to run `collectstatic` now, you'll find that you still get a permissions error.  That's because the current shell session doesn't know that you just added 'denys' to the 'django' group, even though you literally just did it in this very session.  If you like, you can pop open a fresh terminal window, which will now recognize 'denys' as a member of 'django'.  If you now navigate to wherever your `manage.py` is and run `$ python manage.py collectstatic`, it should work.  Otherwise, you'll need to re-load your current shell session with a command like `$ newgrp django`, which will spawn a new session with updated group memberships (be aware that this will erase your previous session's command history from this terminal window).  You'll only need to re-load the shell once, though.  From now on, `collectstatic` should always be able to write files to this `STATIC_ROOT` because the user that runs it has write permissions as group owner of the target directory.

**TL;DR**: The user that runs `manage.py collectstatic` must have write permissions on the target `STATIC_ROOT` folder.  If you don't want to make that user the outright owner of the folder, then the cleanest approach is to create a group for this purpose, make the user that invokes `collectstatic` a member of this group, and give that group ownership and write permissions on the folder.

```
$ sudo groupadd django
$ sudo usermod -a -G django denys
$ newgrp django

$ sudo chgrp django /var/www/app_name/static
$ sudo chmod g+w /var/www/app_name/static
```

Now `$ python manage.py collectstatic` should have all the permissions it needs to work when the user 'denys' invokes it.